# Where to find the sqljdbc_xa.dll file?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, dll, xa

I am trying to enable XA transaction for the `MS sql server 2008` running on `Windows server 2008 R2`.

For that I have to copy the `SQLJDBC_XA.dll` file from the JDBC installation directory to the Binn directory.

This database server doesn't have any such file anywhere in the disk and I don't have access to the installation CDs. Is there any way I could get this specific file?

Comment: The JDBC driver is downloadable from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt484311(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: ^That worked ! I can accept that as the answer too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, the JDBC SQL Server driver can be downloaded from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt484311(v=sql.110).aspx which also contains instructions for configuration etc.

Answer (score 3):

Enabling XA transactions for SQL Server is a non obvious process involving:

(a) Going into Component Services > Distributed Transactions > Local DTC
And ticking a box to enable XA transaction:
See
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2011/10/26/how-a-dba-can-confirm-if-microsoft-jdbc-xa-transactions-are-set/

(b) You have to copy the DLL that comes separably from the DB. Download the latest jdbc driver (e.g. 6.0).
Go to you SQL Server installation folder and search for:
Binn.

You will find a binn folder that already has dlls inside.
E.g. somePath\MicrosoftSQLServer_InstanceRoot\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn

Paste the appropriate:
sqljdbc_6.0\enu\xa\x64\sqljdbc_xa.dll
Dll in there, if you have a 64 bit express edition.
Otherwise, use the 32 bit dll.

If you put the dll in the wrong folder you will get a:

> XAConnection java.sql.SQLException: XA error: XAResource.XAER_RMERR
> start() failed on resource 'someAppDatasource': XAER_RMERR :  A
> resource manager error has occurred in the transaction branch
> javax.transaction.xa.XAException:
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:  Could not load the
> DLL SQLJDBC_XA.dll,  or one of the DLLs it references. Reason: 126(The
> specified module could not be found.).    at
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXAResource.DTC_XA_Interface(SQLServerXAResource.java:742)
> at
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXAResource.start(SQLServerXAResource.java:774)

c) You also get a xa_install.sql
That comes with the driver.
YOu will have to run that sql.
It will create a user role.

(d) You need to go to your used and select database master, and select the new user role that was created for XA transactions.

Sorry, but SQL Server does not make it simple to enable XA transactions ... for whatever reason you have to jump around everywhere ticking boxes to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks! Really helpful answer, I've the same error because of wrong file location!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/understanding-xa-transactions?view=sql-server-ver15

The JDBC XA distributed transaction components are included in the SQL Server engine in SQL Server 2017 starting with cumulative update 16 and in SQL Server 2019, and can be enabled or disabled with a system stored procedure. The sqjdbc_xa.dll from the driver is not required and it is recommended to enable the server components instead for these server versions. To enable the required components to perform XA distributed transactions using the JDBC driver, execute the following stored procedure.

On SQL Server 17 onwards, follow below 2 steps

Step1--> Run the procedure:  EXEC sp_sqljdbc_xa_install

Step2-->To enable MS DTC for XA transactions, follow the steps in link above.

Step3-->Execute below sql on masterdb:
USE master

EXEC sp_grantdbaccess 'testuser', 'testuser'

EXEC sp_addrolemember [SqlJDBCXAUser], 'testuser'